# trigger code after x amount of increments

Tags: javascript, html, variables, game-engine, increment

thanks for looking into this for me.
The issue I am facing is this:
I am keeping track of a variables value, i want to trigger blocks of code after certain values are reached.

currently I am using a switch statement but I am looking for something dynamic.

Example I have now:

```
class className{
  constructor(param){

  this.param = param

  switch(param.x){
    case 25:
      param.y += 0.1;
      break;
    case 50:
      y += 0.1;
      break;
    case 75:
      y += 0.1;
      break;
    }
  }
```

As you can see i want run a block of code after the value of X increments by 25
to manually code each block becomes tedious
i want the same code to run every time the value of x increments by 25
x has no limit and this increments infinitely
so i was looking for some kind of infinite loop or something
does anyone know what I can use for this particular situation

If i could right it like this:

```
param.x.forEach(25){
  param.y += 0.1;
}
```

I did try this above but to no avail it did not work lol 
how can i do this guys any help please?

Comment: Instead of loops and checking `x`, can't you just mathematically derive `y` as `y = Math.floor(x / 25) * 0.1`?

Comment: okay i tried that, but it doesnt work in my code

Comment: i was trying to run it as a class

Comment: ...right because I did remainder instead of integer division, should have been `Math.floor(x / 25) * 0.1`

Comment: wait let me give a better example, check updated question, just refresh

Comment: I think you want sth like `if (x % 25 === 0) y += 0.1;`

Comment: please check the updated question, i am passing arguments ins a class and constructor

Comment: Is `y` a property of a class?

Comment: it is the property of an object constructed by another class yes, it is not a property of the current class that is incrementing it

Comment: @DesignsByCornelius - It's still not clear why you don't calculate `y` as VLAZ showed you.

Comment: see with this code  x has a fixed value, in the code i am using x has no known value and infinitely incrementing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the calculation like this `(x % 25) == 0`

```js
var y = 0;
var x = 0;

function trig() {
  x++;
  console.log(x)
  if ((x % 25) == 0) {
    y += 0.1;
    console.log(y, x)
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  trig()
}, 100)
```

ON Class

```
class className {
  constructor(param) {
    this.param = param
  }
  inc() {
    this.param.x++;
    if ((this.param.x % 25) == 0) {
      this.param.y += 0.1;
    }
  }

  //you could call the inc() function on you click or activity
}
```

Comment: `((x % 25) + 1) * 0.1 === 0.1` is a VERY convoluted way of writing `x % 25 === 0` because the first expression will *only* be true in the case when the second expression is true. But you do two other mathematical operations with that result.

Comment: just tried its breaking my code, for some reason when creating an object from this class now the argument is not being accepted, no errors, it just break my other code -- i am still tinkering to get it to work

Comment: OKAY - i finally got it to work - thanks so much buddy - i just had to work out how to call it in my click events

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can just check if (x % 25 === 0 ){ ..do stuff }